How to create projection matrix?
I have following data:

oblique photos
points representing camera location with x, y, z coordinates (EPSG:2178) and omega, phi, kappa
trapezoids representing photo extent taken from given camera location with omega, phi, kappa
ImageWidth=14192 ImageHeight=10640
PixelSizeX=3.76 PixelSizeY=3.76
camera focal length: 146 mm

This is how it looks like in QGIS:

Am I able to calculate projection matrix from these data and how? Or there’s some missing data?
I would need this projection matrix to serve as an orientation file for SURE https://docs.nframes.com/input-&-output/orientation-formats/projection-matrixes/
I don’t have any other files generated from camera software with its parameters.

Your link does not detail the 12 elements of the sequence of the text file.  Can you clarify which element equals which value?  Still,  it is likely some combination of real-world coordinates (A,B,C,D) in EPSG:2178 as shown above, and the image pixel values where A = (0, 0) and C = (14192, 10640) assuming A and B are the top edge of the image file.  Are you asking how to get the coordinate pairs of A, B, C, and D?  How to write these to the necessary text files?

"Can you clarify which element equals which value?" - this is what I would like to know ;)
I'am asking how to create projection matrix based on my data? I think there is a good explenation https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~16385/s17/Slides/11.1_Camera_matrix.pdf but despite that I get stuck when it comes to adding rotation, translation and something described as "I" in this pdf. I just don't get it. Maybe I don't have enough data for this calculations?
Yes, AB is the top of the image.
General explanation is also provided here https://docs.nframes.com/knowledge-base/coordinate-systems/
